# Error while performing Query. node-mysql.js:15

Tags: mysql, node.js

I tried simple mysql connection in nodejs but got this error, checked with the sql connection....server is up and running....please help!

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '****',
  database : 'todo'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * from < table name >', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (!err)
    console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
  else
    console.log('Error while performing Query.');
});


connection.end();
```

Output:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:48226/9809e9bf-990f-4d1e-9d98-420af454907f
Error while performing Query.
```

Comment: Have you tried printing what `err` is?

Comment: To kjprice - yeah I tried err...it returns me with the err message